Help-paradox: an infinite chess puzzle
In this chess puzzle, the ruleset involves a now-obsolete version of the 3rep draw rule, in which draw is declared upon three consecutive instances of the same series of moves. More precisely, if there is a sequence of moves starting and ending at the same position (which consists of the diagram, side to move, and castling/ep rights), and that sequence occurs thrice in a row, draw is immediately declared. There is no 50m draw rule. Under this ruleset, henceforth called 3loop, chess games can be infinite.
The following position can occur in a legal game of chess. The objective of this puzzle is to produce an infinite sequence of moves such that every finite initial subsequence can occur in a legal game, i.e. there is a proof game for this position followed by that finite sequence in which draw never triggers, but the infinite sequence itself cannot occur no matter what the proof game for this position is.
Thus, under the RS convention for retrograde chess puzzles, every move in this sequence is justified, but the resulting sequence could never actually occur in chess. Combining the notation of chess puzzles with mathematical notation, the puzzle can be compactly presented as follows:


(15+15) h→←∞ (RS)


"...but the infinite sequence itself cannot occur no matter what the proof game for this position is... but the resulting sequence could never actually occur in chess" Infinite sequences cannot occur in chess by default, so you should clarify what you mean.

@fish Infinite sequences can occur under the draw ruleset described in the first paragraph.

EDIT: Addressing problems re: the lack of consideration of the castling rights.
After some further thought I see that the approach I outline below is inadequate as it does not take into account which positions in the "reversible component"(V) can be moved to directly from a position outside of V. If a node in the tree T begins in such a position, then we must include it as one of the T_i we are excluding: otherwise a proof game proceeding directly into this path can form a valid predecessor of the entire sequence. Hence we modify the definition of the tree below by making all nodes with this property leaf nodes. It remains to be shown that the tree is still infinite with this restriction; this amounts to showing that there are infinitely many paths within V to P, with the further restriction that the paths must lie entirely in parts of V not reachable from the complement of V in one move.  To see this, consider the set of positions M in which the pawns, rooks, and kings are in their depicted positions, but the knights may be anywhere except positions which put one of the kings in check(*ETA: not sure if this is needed, but for the sake of simplicity we also label nodes in T with kings in check as leaves).  Now, we can only move from the complement of V into V by moving the pawns, moving the rooks or kings for the first time(losing castling rights), or taking a queen. No position in M can be reached in one move from the complement of V using one of these moves. The pawns cannot have been moved, because the rooks are in their previous positions. The queens cannot have been taken as the kings are occupying their previous positions. If one of the kings or rooks was last to move, it means that the rooks/kings respectively must have moved on a previous move, and therefore castling rights have already been lost. So, the set M cannot be reached in one move from the complement of V; furthermore, it contains arbitrarily long 3loop-free paths leading to P, by moving the knights using some encoding of cubefree binary sequences as outlined below. With these modifications I believe the proof below goes through.
EDIT 2: Also, modify the definition of P by requiring that it's white's move. It has to be white's move after moving here in a normal game because all moves leading from a normal game into P(moving pawn one square, moving knights, moving the king horizontally, moving the rook by one square) change the color of square a piece is on, and therefore flip the overall "color parity" of that piece's side. Initially white and black have the same color parity, so in any position where this is the case it is white's move.

Consider the restriction to positions such that both queens have been taken, the black/white pawns and bishops are in their depicted locations, no knights or rooks have been taken, and all castling rights are gone. Any sequence of moves that ends in the depicted position must enter this set at some point(and further, it must enter this set strictly before reaching the depicted position). Notice that paths in this set are reversible in the sense that if there is a path from a position V0 to V1 in this set, there is a path from V1 to V0. Call this set V.

Consider all possible legal paths from positions in V to the depicted position(call this position P). This set forms an infinite tree T rooted at P, with children of a node being legal paths which can reach that node by a single move(there are infinitely many possible paths because we may construct paths by "twiddling" -- having one player move a single piece back and forth and having another move one of two pieces back and forth. These paths correspond to binary sequences and are 3fold-repetition-free iff the corresponding binary sequence is cube-free, so we can use an infinite cube-free sequence such as the Thue-Morse sequence to construct infinitely many distinct paths)

Consider the infinite tree T. Each node has finitely many branches. Construct a sequence of paths T_i as follows: Proceed inductively through the tree starting at depth j = 0 At each depth j, each node either has infinitely many children or finitely many children. If there are any nodes with finitely many children, add one of these as T_i(choosing between them using some arbitrary fixed method). If there is more than one node with infinitely many children, add one of them as T_i. Otherwise, increment the depth j <-- j+1 and proceed. In this way we construct a sequence T_i of paths such that any possible path from an element of V to P has some T_i as a suffix(but importantly, no finite collection of T_i has this property)

Now we inductively construct an infinite sequence of moves such that any sequence containing a T_i as a suffix has a threefold repetition when followed by this infinite sequence. Let A_(i-1) be the prefix of the sequence we have constructed so far, setting A_0 = []. To define A_i, we consider the sequence B_i = T_(i-1) * A_(i-1). Now, to A_(i-1) we append the following sequence of moves:
(a) D_i, where D_i is "twiddling sequence" as defined above, a sequence of moves where one player moves a piece back and forth and another player moves one of two pieces back and forth, in bijetion with a cubefree binary sequence. D_i is chosen such that |D_i| > 3 |B_i|. Furthermore, the moves of this "twiddling sequence" are chosen such that none of the moves match the last or first move in B_i. This is always possible given the number of moves available to both players in positions in V.
(b) Q_i, where Q_i is a path "inverting" B_i in the sense that it proceeds from the endpoint of B_i to the beginning.
(c) G_i, where G_i is another "twiddling sequence" definied analogously to D_i
(d) B_i
(e) D_i
(f) Q_i
(g) G_i
(h) B_i
(i) D_i
(j) Q_i
(k) G_i
(l) C_i, where C_i is a path to P distinct from T_i


[The twiddling sequences above may not be strictly necessary, I am just including them to avoid any accidental 3fold-repetition.]

This sequence of moves will produce a threefold repetition when prepended by T_i by definition. However, it will not produce a 3fold repetition when prepended by any T_j for j>i. Ergo any finite prefix of this sequence can be part of a legal(3fold-rep free) proof game, but the entire sequence cannot, because any proof game leading to the given position must have some T_i as a suffix, which therefore will produce a 3fold-repetition when preceding a sufficiently large A_i. We define the full infinite sequence A as the limit of A_i as i approaches infinity.


I haven't looked through your whole approach yet, but I noticed the word "castle" doesn't appear in it. Has your approach taken into consideration which positions in V do and don't have castle rights?

Ah, I forgot about the castling rights. I might be missing something, but AFAICT my argument works verbatim if your append "and all castling rights have been lost" to the definition of V

I'll just say this. By the time you fully solve the puzzle, it should be clear why I chose the starting position that I did. It has a lot of special properties.

The tree formalism, vague "twiddling sequence," and post hoc modifications make it hard to distill the exact sequence of moves you've defined, but all the key ideas are here and I'm satisfied this works. I'm accepting this answer, but I implore you to edit this post with a cleaner description of the actual sequence of moves!

Hopefully this level of formality is OK, but I'm happy to provide more details if needed! The main idea should be clear enough, but I haven't found a very clean way to define certain "glueing" move sequences.
Let $P$ be the provided position. One idea is that, for any game reaching $P$, just six "irreversible" things happen: the push of the four a- and h-pawns and the capture of the two queens by two knights (as the bishops haven't moved and the pawns haven't hit the middle ranks, no castling or ep have happened). So, let $\{P_1,....,P_N\}$ be the (clearly finite) set of positions reached by any such game immediately after all six things have happened. By construction, for any game passing by $P$ and ending due to 3rep, the repetition is of a sequence of moves starting after (or when) the respective $P_k$ is reached.
Now, the idea is to construct our paradoxical sequence, which we will call $S$, so that it barely avoids triggering 3rep itself, but does so when prefixed by any sequence of moves leading from one of the $P_k$'s to $P$. We use the notation $s:\text{pos}_1\longrightarrow\text{pos}_2$ to indicate that the sequence of moves $s$ leads from position $\text{pos}_1$ to position $\text{pos}_2$ without coming back to $\text{pos}_1$, and $l(s)$ to denote its length; moreover, we adopt the notation $s_1s_2$ to indicate concatenation of sequences of moves (where the end position of $s_1$ is the starting position of $s_2$). Let: $A=\{(n,k)\in\mathbb{Z}^+\times[1,...,N] : \exists s:P_k\longrightarrow P\text{ s.t. }l(s)=n\}$ ($s$ is taken as not triggering 3rep itself, as is any other sequence we define from scratch) and, for $(n,k)\in A$, let $C(n,k)$ be the set of such $s$, which is finite in virtue of the length condition.
We give an iterative construction. Initialize counters $n=1,k=1$. In the initial state the position is $P$ and $\bar{S}=\emptyset$.

If $(n,k)\in A$, enumerate $C(n,k)=\{c_1,...,c_r\}$; then, for $i=1,...,r$:


let $\bar{S}$ be the partial sequence constructed until now;
reach $P_k$ (from $P$) with a suitable sequence $s_{n,k,i}$ tbdl; position: $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}$;
come back to $P$ with $c_i$; position: $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}c_i$;
concatenate $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}c_i$, then concatenate $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}$, and finally come back to $P$ with a suitable sequence $t_{n,k,i}$ not having $c_i$ as an initial segment and satisfying other conditions tbdl; position: $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}c_i\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}c_i\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}t_{n,k,i}$;


increase $(n,k)\in\mathbb{Z}^+\times[1,...,N]$ lexicographically (so that we get $(n,k+1)$ unless $k=N$, in which case we get $(n+1,1)$).

$S$ is the sequence obtained by letting this process run ad infinitum. It is an infinite sequence, i.e. there are arbitrarily long sequences of moves leading from some $P_k$ to $P$ (while this isn't exactly trivial, it isn't harder than showing that arbitrarily long games can happen with 3loop). Let us show that it has the required properties:
$S$ triggers 3rep for any proof game leading to $P$: given such a game, we let $P_k$ be the position immediately after all six irreversible things happen, and let $s:P_k\longrightarrow P$ be the relative move sequence (if in the game the sequence goes back to $P_k$ before reaching $P$, we take $s$ as its final segment which does not do so); then, necessarily $(l(s),k)\in A$ and $s\in C(l(s),k)$, so $s$ appears as a $c_i$ at some point in $S$ (see 2. above) and, by 3., we then trigger 3rep for the sequence of moves $s\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}s\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}s\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}$ starting and ending at $P_k$.
For any finite initial segment of $S$ there is a proof game that does not trigger 3rep: given such a segment $S_0$, there is $n_0$ such that all moves of $S_0$ are generated by our algorithm without the first counter reaching $n_0$; take $(n,k)\in A$ such that there exists $\sigma_2\in C(n,k)$ whose last $n_0$ moves do not lead to any of the $P_i$'s, nor to $P$ before the whole sequence ends (this is not a problem: it is enough for one to start with a position where either all the rooks have been lifted and only one knight is on d1/d8, or no knights are on d1/d8 and only a rook has not been lifted, and then to never, in the last $n_0$ moves, bring a rook to the first/last rank or a knight to d1 or d8; the kings and knights are enough to construct the sequence without triggering 3rep) and consider any proof game $\sigma_1$ for $P_k$. I claim that (for a suitable choice of the $s_{n,k,i}$'s, $t_{n,k,i}$'s) $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ is a proof game for $P$ that does not trigger 3rep when suffixed with $S_0$. Indeed, as already observed, a sequence of moves triggering 3rep can only happen after $P_k$ is reached, i.e. in $\sigma_2S_0$. But such a sequence cannot start before $\sigma_2$ has been played out: if a final segment of $\sigma_2$ appears in $S_0$, by the additional requirement above it does not do so as a $c_i$ for some $(n,k)$, so by construction it cannot lead to 3rep being triggered. Therefore, we are left with the task of showing that $S$ itself does not trigger 3rep.
This can be shown by induction on our counters $(n,k,i): (n,k)\in A, i\in [1,...,\#C(n,k)]$ in lexicographical order. Indeed, adopting the notation from the algorithm, for the base case $\bar{S}=\emptyset$ we need to show that $s_{n,k,i}c_is_{n,k,i}c_is_{n,k,i}t_{n,k,i}$ does not trigger 3rep; choosing $s_{n,k,i}$ as short as possible and not passing through $P_k$ before its end, by our assumption on the sequences in $A$ we easily find that the only ways a threefold repetition could happen are if it happened in $s_{n,k,i}t_{n,k,i}$ - which, be the requirement we just imposed, we can rule out just by asking that $t_{n,k,i}$ does not contain a double repetition - or if $c_i$ was an initial segment of $t_{n,k,i}$, which is impossible by 3). For the inductive step, suppose there was a subsegment $\sigma$ appearing three times in a row; we have two cases:
a) the repetition is contained in either $\bar{S}s_kc_i$ or $\bar{S}s_kt_{k,i}$, or
b) it isn't.
In case a), by our choice of $s_{n,k,i}$ not reaching $P_k$ before its end, we see that necessarily $\sigma$ is a subsegment of $\bar{S}$, and either a 3rep is triggered by $\bar{S}s_k$ or else $\sigma$ reaches position $P_k$. To rule out the first subcase we just need to require in 3) that $t_{n,k,i}$ does not appear in $\bar{S}$, as then 3rep would necessarily be triggered in $t_{m,l,j}s_{n,k,i}$ with $t_{m,l,j}$ the sequence that $\bar{S}$ ends in, but as $t_{m,l,j}$ has no double repetition by our choice, this would require $s_{n,k,i}$ to start wit a loop at $P$, contradicting the "as short as possible" requirement. In the last subcase, as all three copies of $\sigma$ must reach $P_k$, by construction of $\bar{S}$, $\sigma$ contains a sequence of moves $P\longrightarrow P_k$ or one $P_k\longrightarrow P$; therefore, (the third instance of) $\sigma$ necessarily contains either $s_{n,k,i}$ or $c_i$ (resp. $t_{n,k,i}$), and as $c_i$ (resp. $t_{n,k,i}$) does not appear in $\bar{S}$, we simply need to add the requirement that $s_{n,k,i}$ also does not appear in $\bar{S}$ to reach an absurd.
In case b), we deal with the subcase in which the first instance of $\sigma$ is a subsegment of $\bar{S}$ as above (it will necessarily reach $P_k$). Otherwise, it will either:

contain either $s_{n,k,i}$ or $c_i$ as a subsegment; in this case, the properties and arguments we already discussed (an initial segment of $c_i$ cannot appear in $s_{n,k,i}$, a final segment of $s_{n,k,i}$ cannot appear in $c_i$, both sequences do not appear in $\bar{S}$ and $s_{n,k,i}$ does not pass through $P_k$) show that, in the second and third instance of $\sigma$, $s_{n,k,i}$ (resp. $c_i$) cannot be "overlayed" anywhere else except on the second and third instances of $s_{n,k,i}$ (resp $c_i$), so $\sigma$ has to be $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}c_i$, and we are again done by 3);
be a subsegment of all of $\bar{S}s_{n,k,i}$, $s_{n,k,i}c_i$ and $c_i\bar{S}$, and not be contained in any of $\bar{S},s_{n,k,i},c_i$; $\sigma$ must reach $P_k$ just once by the second containment, and hence reach $P$ from there by the first; then by the third, we get that $t_{n,k,i-1}$ (or $t_{n',k,r}$ for some $n'<n$ if $i=1$, but this does not matter) is a starting segment of $c_1\in C(m,k)$ for $m$ the least positive integer such that $C(m,k)\neq\emptyset$. This contradicts 3). As we can easily take $s_{n,k,i}$ and $t_{n,k,i}$ with all the required properties, we are done.


You did not successfully list all irreversible things which have occurred. The loss of the four castling rights occurred at some point.

Very cool puzzle! This may be a little rough, but here's my initial attempt at a construction. EDIT: See the bottom for an updated solution. EDIT 2: Updated solution to account for the loss of castling rights and correct the section on the reversible sequence
High Level Idea
Key idea: the puzzle constructs an "infinite" move-cycle where, on any finite prefix, we never quite meet the 3loop rule, but if you tried to play out the entire infinite sequence from the starting diagram, eventually a threefold repetition of the sequence (not merely the position) would occur and force a draw.
Constructing an Infinite Family of Cycles
First, we will produce an infinite family of mini-cycles ${C_k}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that:

Each $C_k$ starts and ends in the same position $P$ (including side to move and rights).
$C_k \neq C_m$ for $k \neq m$; that is, they are pairwise distinct as sequences of moves.

Hence we have an unbounded supply of distinct cycles to use in our larger "no triple in any finite prefix, but eventually a triple" construction.
We will concentrate on a knight "out-and-back" example for concreteness, but the same proof idea applies to bishop dances, rook dances, or any other piece maneuvers that preserve the position.
Statement
Position $P$: We assume there is a position $P$ on the board (the puzzle's diagram) with White to move. We want to build infinitely many cycles
$C_1, C_2, C_3, \ldots$
where each $C_k$ is a finite sequence of legal moves that starts at $(P, \text{White to move})$ and ends again in $(P, \text{White to move})$.
Defining cycle $C_k$

We choose one White knight (say, initially on g1) and one Black knight (initially on g8).

In cycle $C_k$, the White knight makes $2k$ moves that take it on some path from g1 out into the board and then back again to g1, while the Black knight similarly makes $2k$ moves from g8 out and back to g8.

The moves are interleaved to maintain alternating White/Black turns, but White's first move is always the knight on g1, and we end exactly after Black's last knight-move.

The total length of $C_k$ is therefore $4k$ half-moves (that is, $2k$ White moves + $2k$ Black moves).

After these $4k$ half-moves, it is once again White to move in the same position $P$. (Nothing else changed: no pawns moved two squares, no rooks or kings moved, etc., so castling/en-passant rights remain identical.)


Note that a path of $2k$ consecutive knight moves that starts and ends on the same square is always possible on an otherwise open board -- especially in the puzzle diagram where the center is clear. The knight can always zig-zag around harmlessly, as long as it does not illegally land on an occupied square or leave the board.
Thus, for each integer $k \geq 1$, we have a distinct cycle of length $4k$.
Distinctness
We must show that $C_k \neq C_m$ for $k \neq m$. The simplest way:

Cycle length: $C_k$ has exactly $4k$ half-moves.
If $k \neq m$, then $4k \neq 4m$.

Hence one of them is a sequence of $4k$ moves, while the other is a sequence of $4m$ moves (with $k \neq m$). No two finite move-sequences of different lengths can be identical as sequences.
Therefore, these cycles are pairwise different:
$C_1 \neq C_2 \neq C_3 \neq \ldots$
Note that even if we wanted to allow the same length but different routes, we could also vary the path the knight takes so that each cycle has a unique "signature." But the length argument alone is the simplest: no two lengths match, so they can't be the same sequence.
Thus we have infinitely many distinct mini-cycles.
Returning to the same position $P$
Next, we show that each $C_k$ indeed returns to the exact same position $P$.

White Knight: In cycle $C_k$, White's knight makes $2k$ moves in total, an out-and-back path. It starts on g1 (or wherever it begins in the puzzle position) and ends on that same square, with no net effect on the board.

Black Knight: Similarly does an out-and-back path of $2k$ moves, also returning to g8.

No other pieces move at all (kings and rooks remain in place, pawns do nothing). So no castling or en-passant changes occur, no captures, etc.

The total cycle has $4k$ half-moves, so an even number of half-moves. Since White starts the first half-move, after an even number of half-moves, it is White's turn again.


Hence the net effect is:

White to move again,
The knights are back on their original squares,
The entire board (including rights) is unchanged.

So the final position is exactly $P$ (with White to move).
Constructing an Infinite Sequence
Next, we inductively build longer and longer partial sequences.
We will define a growing family of finite sequences
$S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \ldots$
each of which is a list of cycles (so each $S_n$ is something like $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{L_n})$, a finite string of cycles), with these properties:

No triple repeat so far: in $S_n$, you never see the same cycle repeated three times in a row.

Increasing length: $S_{n+1}$ extends $S_n$ by appending some new cycles at the end (so the prefix remains the same, but we get a longer list).


Concretely:
Let $S_1$ be any finite sequence of cycles you like—e.g., just $(C_1)$. There's no triple repetition in a single cycle.
Inductive step: Suppose you have built $S_n$ of length $L_n$. You want to create $S_{n+1}$.
Look at $S_n$. If the last two cycles of $S_n$ are repetitions of the same cycle, then appending another such cycle would create a triple. We do not want to do that yet, because we need property 1 to remain true in $S_{n+1}$.
So, if the last two were instances of the same cycle $C_\star$, we insert at least one "buffer" cycle $C_{\text{buffer}} \neq C_\star$ to break the triple. We have infinitely many distinct cycles to choose from, so pick any that doesn't cause a triple.
Now, we have an increasing chain of finite sequences $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \ldots$ such that each $S_n$ has no triple.
We can define our final sequence to be $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{3rep}$, where $\circ$ denotes concatenation. We will use this below when building the components of our solution.
Solution Based on Proof Games for $P$
For any proof game producing $P$, we note that there are 10 "irreversible" moves which have occurred (the four pawns advancing, the two queens being taken, and the loss of four castling rights).
The key point is that a reversible sequence must occur after all "irreversible" moves have happened (no ep has happened). Denote the sequence of moves which follows the final irreversible move and transforms the position resulting from that move to $P$ as $S_{tail}$.
$S_{tail}$ cannot be empty (i.e., there must be at least one reversible move following the final irreversible move). To see this, notice that if final irreversible move is a pawn move, then $S_{tail}$ at least contains the moves needed to place one rook and knight in their positions in $P$ (since each rook cannot advance until its respective pawn has, and each knight cannot move to its position in $P$ until its rook has advanced). If a queen being taken is the final irreversible move, meaning that castling rights have already been eliminated due to the rooks moving (or some rooks moving along with a  king moving) and the pawns have advanced, then $S_{tail}$ includes at the very least the moves needed to place the knight that captured that queen in position as well as the moves needed to place one king in position (since its displayed position would have been occupied by the queen). If the final irreversible move is the loss of castling rights, then this is caused either by a rook moving or a king moving. If it is caused by a king moving, then there must be at least one rook not in its position in $P$ (otherwise, all four rooks would have moved and castling rights would have already been lost), so $S_{tail}$ includes at least the final rook moves before it ends up in that position. If it is caused by a rook moving, then there is at least one king not in its position in $P$, since if all kings had moved to their positions in $P$ castling rights would have been lost already, and so $S_{tail}$ includes at least the final king moves such that it ends in its position in $P$ as well as the moves needed for the knight to move into position after the rook.
So, we know that $S_{tail}$ is not empty and, in particular, it consists of reversible moves which lead to $P$. Denote the position which preceded the sequence $S_{tail}$ as $P_0$. Finally, note that we can always undo the sequence $S_{tail}$ to return to $P_0$ from $P$ since $S_{tail}$ is reversible and all irreversible moves have been completed by the time we have reached $P_0$. We will call the sequence that undoes $S_{tail}$ and transforms $P$ to $P_0$ as $S_{tail}^{-1}$.
Construction
To build our 3rep construction, we will build three "blocks" $B$, consisting of cycles from our infinite family, $S_{tail}$, and $S_{tail}^{-1}$. Our construction, when concatenated with any history leading to $P$, will produce three long sequences which return to $P_0$, triggering the rule.
Similar to the construction above, we construct a growing family of finite sequences
$S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \ldots$, ensuring that no triples occur during our construction. Then we define our blocks as:
$B_0 = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{tail}^{-1}$
$B_1 = S_{tail} \circ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{tail}^{-1}$
$B_2 = B_1$
Thus, each block ends at position $P_0$. Now, concatenating $B_0 \circ B_1 \circ B_2$ to any proof history will produce a sequence of moves:
$S_{tail} \circ B_0 \circ B_1 \circ B_2$
$= S_{tail} \circ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{tail}^{-1} \circ S_{tail} \circ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{tail}^{-1} \circ S_{tail} \circ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{tail}^{-1}$
During this sequence, we can guarantee that castling rights remain consistent from $P_0$, since they have already been lost, and there are no changes to ep rights.
Since $S_{tail} \circ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i \circ S_{tail}^{-1}$ occurs three times, starting and ending at $P_0$ each time, it triggers the 3loop rule, but any finite initial subsequence will not.
Guaranteeing Achievability
Even though we can choose our cycles to guarantee that no triples appear in $B_i$ for any $i$, it may still be the case that appending our infinite sequence to some proof game produces a triple. The position $P$ guarantees that we can construct such a sequence, however. Specifically, the position guarantees that there are multiple (infinite) histories that can be constructed for $P$ and that these histories do not contain mandatory subsequences.
The position is "dead" in terms of irreversible changes:

All pawns advanced exactly one square - no en passant possible

Queens captured - no further captures forced

All castling rights lost - no forced king/rook moves


We can construct multiple valid $S_{tail}$ sequences for any proof game leading to $P_0$ due to:

Piece mobility: Knights can reach final squares via multiple paths after rooks move and rooks can take multiple paths before reaching their final position.

Rook Positioning: The rooks being behind pawns makes all rook moves were reversible (they couldn't have captured queens since they never crossed the pawn line). This guarantees the queens were captured by knights

King-Bishop-Knight Pattern: With castling rights lost but kings central, this formation allows kings to move multiple times reversibly. This maximizes move freedom in $S_{tail}$

King-Rook independence: After castling rights are lost, kings and rooks can move in different orders


This multiplicity ensures no accidental early 3-loop triggers, as different proof games can have different $S_{tail}$ sequences.
Avoiding Draw in First N Moves
Given an infinite sequence as we have constructed above, we want to ensure that any finite initial sequence does not produce a draw. Concretely, for any N, we construct a proof game PG(N) for P such that appending the first N moves of our sequence doesn't trigger 3loop.
Construction:

Let L be the length of $S_{tail}$

Let M be max length of any cycle used in first N moves

Choose proof game PG(N) with length > 3(N + L + M)


This ensures that the total number of moves = Length(PG(N)) + N < 3(Length(Stail) + Length(Cycle)). This means that we do not have enough moves to complete three full cycles, so a draw cannot be triggered.
The position $P$ allows us to construct such long proof games since knights, rooks, and kings have multiple paths to their final positions (even the king can just move back and forth). The order of irreversible moves is not fixed, so they can always be reordered. There are no forced patterns in the move sequences leading to $P$, particularly in the reversible sequence, so we can always avoid unintended repetitions. Additionally, we can make the reversible sequence $S_{tail}$ arbitrarily large, ensuring that we can choose $S_{tail}$ with length L for all but a finite number of small L.
Thus, we can always choose a proof game that guarantees no early 3loop trigger in the first N moves of our infinite sequence.

I’m confused by “any finite prefix.” Clearly the full game prefix can’t occur any time past this position, since there are no longer 32 pieces on the board.

Sorry, by that I mean "any finite prefix starting from the displayed position". We assume the displayed position can occur in a legal game

Sure, but your objective is to produce a sequence such that, for any history of this position (the moves from the standard chess opening position to here), if you then append this infinite sequence, a draw will be triggered. You will have to discuss the ways by which this position can be reached from the game start to analyze this question.

Oh, I see. I misunderstood in that case. I thought you meant to produce a sequence starting from this position regardless of how it was reached.

I still don’t really see the key ideas needed to solve this. In particular, what are you doing to ensure every finite initial subsequence is achievable? What do the histories look like before P for a large initial subsequence?

Every finite initial subsequence leading to P or every finite initial subsequence following P? The latter is guaranteed by the the construction of the blocks and cycles, unless I'm misunderstanding you

The latter. For large N, how do you construct a history for P such that appending the first N moves of your constructed sequence does not result in draw?

You're right, I didn't make it explicit. I thought I was given some concrete history and then construct the infinite sequence based on that, so that the construction works given any specific history

If you allow transfinite sequences then the infinite sequence $TTTT$ does the job, where $T$ is the Thue-Morse sequence
$01101001100101101001011001101001...$
By the symbol “0” I mean the sequence of moves (White king, black king, white king, black king)
And by the symbol “1” I mean the sequence of moves (white knight, black knight, white knight goes back, black knight goes back).
Remark: I can change the definition of symbols “0” and “1” based on the last sequence of moves played to reach the position in the picture (so that concatenating T to the initial sequence s doesn’t give us a cube (subsequence XXX) in the overlap between the end of s and the beginning of T).

Transfinite sequences are not allowed, or even well-defined here.
